# Web API POST method returns HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

As the title says i have got a 500 internal server error when using post method of a Web API. The Get method is working fine, just getting error in POST.

I am using fidler to send post request :

**Response Header:**
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

**Request Header:**
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:45379
Content-Type: application/jsonContent-Length: 41
Content-Length: 41

**Request Body:**
{"iduser"="123456789","username"="orange"}

**Here is my code for post method:**

```
     // POST api/User
     public HttpResponseMessage Postuser(user user)
     {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response =R  equest.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = user.iduser }));
            return response;
       }
       else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

**Sooooooo what could have possibly gone wrong? Why its not allowing me to POST?**

Comment: So have you tried running it with the debugger on, to see what is happening to your request? That seems like a necessary first step for working out what could have gone wrong.

Comment: Your request body has a typo/ You're missing a quote `"` after the user id.

Comment: Yep i used breakpoints on post method but they are not being hit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The data in your post is not a valid JSON-object, which is what the model binder is expecting (Content-Type: application/json).

```
{"iduser"="123456789","username"="orange"}
```

Try replacing your = with : and see how you get on. Your code works on my machine with those alterations in the request.

```
POST http://localhost:20377/api/test/Postuser HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:20377
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 42
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,nb;q=0.4,de;q=0.2

{"iduser":"123456789","username":"orange"}
```

Comment: In my case, I was using same URL in two different controllers but they had different request body.