# Error 500 launching the Web Service Explorer with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web, service, explorer

I created my first web service and all seems to run ok, but when I launch the Web Service Explorer, it returns a **HTTP ERROR: 500**.

I'm using the version Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) of Eclipse, Tomcat 8.0.14, Axis2 1.6.2 and JRE 1.8.0_25. I read that it's solved changing the version to jre7, but i didn't work.

[Edited]
What I was doing is this [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html). The problem comes when I tried the [second part](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.0/tutorials/WebServiceExplorer/WebServiceExplorer.html). Instead of appears the Web Services Explorer I get the **500 Error**.

Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: this seems like internal server error. This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618745/web-api-post-method-returns-http-1-1-500-internal-server-error , if not then describe it

Comment: I don't make any http resquest in my service. I'll modify the question to give more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing JAVA_HOME and path to 1.7 JDK instead of 1.8. The problem is due to java 8 which doesn't seem to be compatible with luna as of now.

Comment: thank you very much! I didn't try it before because I didn't need anymore since now... xD But thanx!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with Eclipse kepler when launching the Web Services Explorer-- I had jdk1.8 installed. Tried changing the JAVA_HOME (path points to %JAVA_HOME%) to point to jdk1.7 and still got the same issue.

After some research I decided to go with uninstalling jdk1.8 and this worked (somehow).

Totally a work around and not a solution; This got the Web Services Explorer to work for me.